# Which connection string for MySql ODBC connector 5.2.6?

Tags: mysql, connection-string

it seems i can't make work a connection to MySql using ODBC connector 5.2.6.
In a 64 bit environment, in a VBA excel application, i use this string, but it not work:

> "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2
>   Driver}; Server=myserver;Database=mydb;User=readonly;Password=mypass;Option=3"

I have also used

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver}
```

and

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver}
```

But the error is: ODBC driver unknow.

Can someone help me ?

Ps: it works with a DSN setted, but i would like to use a connection string so i don't go to each user computer and set a DSN.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Quick Answer

Make sure you have installed the correct ODBC version (64-bit or 32-bit), matching the software.
Try the following:

- Replace `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver}` with `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver}`
- Replace `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver}` with `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver}`

---

### Long Answer

The `Driver={driver name}` part of an ODBC connection string is the driver name that is listed in the **Data Sources (ODBC)** dialog.

Because you are running in a 64-bit environment, what you do next depends on whether you are running Excel (or whatever the software, web app etc.) as 32-bit or 64-bit, and therefore make sure you've installed the appropriate MySQL ODBC driver version. This is probably the most common problem people run into with ODBC drivers on 64-bit systems.

For those running web servers and trying to get 32-bit ODBC drivers to work in their 32-bit web app, make sure you enable 32-bit applications on the application pool. Here is a forum post describing how to do this: http://forums.iis.net/post/2023543.aspx

#### 64-bit

If the software is 64-bit then open the *Run* dialog box, and run `%windir%\System32\odbcad32.exe`.
Click the *Drivers* tab, and find the MySQL ODBC driver listed, remember the name in the *Name* column, and use that in the connection string. 
For 5.2.6 this will most likely be: `MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver`

Where the driver name you tried before was `5.2w` use the `Unicode` driver, where it was `5.2a` use the `ANSI` driver.

#### 32-bit

If the software is 32-bit then in the *Run* dialog box run `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` to open the 32-bit *Data Sources* dialog, and then do the same as above.
On 64-bit machines using the 32-bit driver, it is recommended to start the connection string with `Provider=MSDASQL;`

Comment: I have use ODBC version 5.3.6
as such the connection string is:

"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};SERVER=server_name;UID=user_id;PWD=password;DATABASE=database;Option=3;

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Access 2010/2013 and windows 7.  I  assumed that I needed the 64 bit driver for a 64 bit environment and could not make a connection whatever I did.  I finally downloaded and installed the 32bit version and am now able to connect to MySQL database on a remote server.  As Excel is an also Office product I expect the problem/solution is the same.